# Fast Vector rendering library for C or Python

Tags: graphics, vector

I'm looking for a library like Cairo, just far faster. It has to be a library that works with C or Python. It also would be nice if I could output to PNG, and SVG. I am looking at Qt's arthur, but that's C++, and I'm not a fan. 
Any suggestions?

Edit: another precondition is that it has to run under Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has [aggdraw](http://effbot.org/zone/aggdraw-index.htm)

Comment: Aggdraw is based off AGG? (Anti-grain-graphics). Last time I checked that was a tiny bit slower than Cairo.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what's fast, but here's a [rendering comparison](http://web.archive.org/web/20100105151758/http://www.linuxrising.org/svg_test/).

Edit: Apparently [Xara](http://www.xaraxtreme.org/about-performance.html) is supposed to be much faster than Cairo.

Comment: Unfortunately essential elements of Xara's renderer are not open-source. Great app, but their Linux effort seems to have died, sadly.

Answer (score 1):

Google's Chrome browser and Android platform make use of their Skia vector library.

I heard second-hand that Vladimir Vukicevic has quickly ported Cairo to be able to use Skia.  A quick googling seems to confirm it:

http://people.mozilla.com/~vladimir/misc/cairo-skia.patch

Not sure when or if this is mainstream, but I'd anticipate a major speed-up across the board!

Comment: Do you have a link to the Skia library's home page?

Comment: afraid not Sargun, but the code is online and there's some background at http://www.satine.org/archives/2008/09/02/skia-source-code-released/
I've heard its good at gradient fills and things, and I've seen in the code it has a GL backend for HW acceleration.  Whats good on phones is also good on PCs

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL?

It can do 2D pretty well. :)